# what are the causal tests that can be used for proving causation?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation, mathematical-statistics, causality

Which are the various causal tests in statistics which can be done in R?
I have data for some months, with 2 variables. But I am not able to prove causation in between.

Answer (score 3):

No statistical test *proves* causation.

Such relations can be strongly supported from data produced by a particular experimental design. Usually this design associates to a randomised experiment but there is a huge body of work for observational studies as well. (see for example the book on "[Explanation in Causal Inference](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Explanation-Causal-Inference-Mediation-Interaction/dp/0199325871)" by VanderWeele or "[Counterfactuals and Causal Inference](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Counterfactuals-Causal-Inference-Principles-Analytical/dp/1107694167)" by Morgan and Wimnship) In any case, the data and evidence we gather *strongly imply* rather then *prove* causation. You specifically mention temporal data: in the case of temporal data it might be a lucrative idea to assume a causal relation but this can be a red herring; this matter was extensively discussed on the CV thread on: "[Correlation does not imply causation; but what about when one of the variables is time?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284096)".

`R` allows you to try a variety of cutting-edge algorithms to assess causality relations. Off the top of my head I can think of the packages [`pcalg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcalg/index.html), [`InvariantCausalPrediction`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/InvariantCausalPrediction/index.html), [`CausalImpact`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CausalImpact/index.html) to mention three packages one could try. Again, the results from the packages do *not* prove but *provide strong evidence* for causal relations.